# Add entries to array under specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping through a set of trips, and every trip has a `End-Station`. It is possible to select a broad date range, such that there are multiple trips for the same `End-Station`. My goal is to add trips from another "date" to an array which already has an entry for a `End-Station`.

```
if(typeof(theResponse[current]) !== 'undefined') {
    for(var i=0; i < theResponse[current].length; i++) {

        var station = theResponse[current][i];
        Trips.push({
            EndStation: station.EndStationID, // Is the same for any theResponse[current][i]
            TripsOut: station.Tripcount,      // This should be added under the same "EndStation"
            Enabled: true,
            Trips: station.Trips
    })
    }
} else {
    console.log("sorry, no trips.");
}
```

For example: `TripsOut` might be 5 for `theResponse[current][1]` for a particular `End-Station`, and then it is 6 for `theResponse[current][2]` for that same End-Station. How can I **add** these two such that there is a single entry (in this case 11) under the specific station? Currently, it creates another entry, so there are multiple entries for the same End-Station.

Comment: Search for the item in the array and if it exists update it instead of pushing a new one? Or use an object instead of an array, with the `EndStationID` as the key for each property, so you can look it up directly rather than searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed above advice and check if the "End-Station" already exists in the array, then update accordingly:

```
var station = theResponse[current][i];
var index = Trips.findIndex(x => x.EndStation == station.EndStation);
if(index !== -1) {
    Trips[index].TripsOut = Trips[index].TripsOut + station.Tripcount; // Add to existing value
    Trips[index].Trips.push(station.Trips); // Is an array, so push to append
} else {
    tripDetails.push({
        EndStation: station.EndStation,
        TripsOut: station.Tripcount,
        Enabled: true,
        Trips: station.Trips
    })
}
```